# how to use bitwise operators to covert 32 bit decimal to hexadecimal in c?

Tags: arrays, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am supposed to write a function where a 32 bit decimal is converted to hexadecimal. But my function keeps outputting zero instead of the correct hexadecimal. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Below is the code to my function.

input: 66

what the output should be: 42

what my code outputs: 0

```
uint32_t packed_bcd(uint32_t value) {
    uint32_t ones = 15;
    uint32_t mask = (ones >> 28);

    uint32_t numbers[8];
    numbers[0] = value & mask;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        uint32_t mask_temp = (mask << (4 * i));
        numbers[i] = mask_temp & value;
    }

    for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        numbers[i] = numbers[i] * pow(10, i);
    }

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        sum = sum + numbers[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: @beaker that was just a printf statement for debugging, have removed it now, error is still there.

Comment: you're allowed to use `pow`?

Comment: @yano yes i am allowed

Comment: @yano never ever do it

Comment: @0___________ is it the pow thats causing the wrong output?

Comment: Not sure I'm really getting this then. Your function accepts a `uint32_t` and returns a `uint32_t`. `value` is a number,, you display that in base 2, 8, 10, 16,, whatever base you want. The number itself is still the same, there's no "conversion" to be done. If anything, seems like your function should be returning a string or something so `value` is displayed in base 16

Comment: The name "packed_bcd" suggests that for input of 0x66 (BCD) the output should be 0x42.  Anyway, in a debugger step through and look at the values of your variables, particularly mask.

Comment: `ones >> 28` won't this always be zero? Since the 1 is at the right-hand 'edge' of the number, and you're shifting it further to the right? What did you intend this line to do?

Comment: @stark i just checked, mask has a value of 0, but its supposed be 15. I dont know how to fix this.

Comment: ferocioussprouts, Note with `uint32_t ones = 1;  uint32_t mask = (ones >> 28);`, `mask` is 0.  Did you want `<<`?

Comment: @Korosia in that line i pretty much want the last four binary digits to be 1. How do i do this?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica in that line, i want the last four bits to be 1111 (the bits before those should all be zeros) how do i do this?

Comment: "want the last four binary digits to be 1" --> `ones = 0XF;` if _last_ means least significant bits.  Or  `ones = 0XF0000000;` if _last_ means most significant bits.

Comment: ferocioussprouts, `uint32_t ones = 15;  uint32_t mask = (ones >> 28);` still makes for `mask` to be 0.  Be clear, the _last_ of what?  The last of `value, ones, mask, ...`.  Instead of _last_, suggest _most_ or _least_ significant bits.  Bits in an integer do not have a specified first/last order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BCD is not hex or normal binary.

```
uint32_t bcdtobin(uint32_t bcd)
{
    uint32_t result = 0;
    uint32_t mask = 1;

    while(bcd)
    {
        result += (bcd & 0x0f) * mask;
        bcd >>= 4;
        mask *= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

uint32_t bintobcd(uint32_t bin)
{
    uint32_t result = 0;
    size_t remaining = 32;

    if(bin <= 99999999)
    {
        while(bin)
        {
            result >>= 4;
            result |= (bin % 10) << 28;
            bin /= 10;
            remaining -= 4;
        }
        result >>= remaining;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using your example number:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", bintobcd(42));
    printf("%d\n", bcdtobin(66));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9K48GEosv